# Using HOG to get image descriptors but hog.compute always returns 0.0

Tags: python, opencv

[64x64 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEYJ9.jpg)
Trying to use OpenCV to do something simple in Python. Using HOG to get the feature vector. But I get all 0.0. I've tried a few images same result.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("D:\\skhan\\research\\data\\face\\test.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.0
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 64
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
winStride = (8,8)
padding = (8,8)
locations = ((10,20),)
hist = hog.compute(image,winStride,padding,locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `hist = hog.compute(image)` gives a non-zero result.

By default `winstride, padding, locations` are empty tuples. However, if you are firm on using `winstride`, etc your image is 64x64 and your window size (`winsize`) is 64x64, adding a 8x8 `winstride` will cause no overlapping of the window on the image, hence your output is filled with zeros.

To clarify, `winsize` is the size of the sliding window that is run across the entire image. Since the size of the image and the sliding window is the same, due to the manner in which HoG features are calculated, there will be no features created, which is why you're seeing zeros.